Model is null in ASP.NET Core OData POST action
When trying to save a new row on my Course entity by Post endpoint from my ODataController, I got an error:

The input was not valid.\r\n\r\nCourse:\r\nThe Course field is required.

When using the Put endpoint with an existing Guid, it works for some reason.
When using breakpoints in the Post endpoint, my Course entity is null even if my payload sent by my front is the same from the one I send to the Put endpoint.
I also tried to add "Course": {} to my JsonBody with no luck.
I went through this post: How can I resolve .NET Core with EF Core required field error? and tried every solutions provided with no luck.
I really don't understand what I am missing.
Here's my CourseController:
using System.Net;
using SyncSchools.WebServices.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Deltas;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SyncSchools.WebServices.Controllers.Odata
{
    public class CoursesController : ODataController
    {
        SyncSchoolsContext _dbContext = new SyncSchoolsContext();

        [HttpPost]
        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        // POST odata/Course
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Course Course)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return (IActionResult)BadRequest(ModelState);

            return await SaveChanges(Course);
        }
        private async Task<IActionResult> SaveChanges(Course data)
        {
            var existing = _dbContext.Courses.Find(data.Id);

            var dbentry = _dbContext.Entry(data);

            if (existing == null)
            {
                data.Id = new Guid();
                data.Deleted = false;
                data.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                _dbContext.Courses.Add(data);
            }
            else
            {
                data.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                _dbContext.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(data);
            }

            try
            {
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            if (existing == null)
                return (IActionResult)Created(data);
            else
                return (IActionResult)Updated(data);
        }
    }
}

Here are the linked entities:
Course.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SyncSchools.WebServices.Models
{
    public class Course
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Course()
        {
            this.Classes = new HashSet<Class>();
        }

        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public bool? Deleted { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
        public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Class>? Classes { get; set; }
    }
}

Class.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SyncSchools.WebServices.Models
{
    public class Class
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Class()
        {
            Users = new HashSet<User>();
            Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
        }

        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public Guid? CityId { get; set; }

        public bool? Deleted { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
        public string? UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CityId))]
        public virtual City? City { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<User>? Users { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Course>? Courses { get; set; }
    }
}

Any help would be welcome.

EF is an ORM, it has nothing to do with HTTP and doesn't care about POST or PUT

Please include only the relevant code. The SaveChange() method is wrong, but it's not even visible without scrolling. There's no reason at all to use .Entry() calls. If the object is found, it's already tracked. If not, you need to attach it with Add or Update. If the entity has a database-generated key, just Update is enough to determine whether the entity is Added or Modified. If you check the ASP.NET Core Getting Started tutorials you'll see that just 2-3 lines are more than enough to do what you want.

Trying to use one method for everything causes more harm than good. SaveChanges essentially tries to guess whether it was called by Post or Put. Using a client-side GUID prevents the easy use of Update and results in database fragmentation, for no benefit. If want to insert a complex object graph, EF will insert the objects in the proper order and fix up their database-generated identities itself

Thanks for these insights, but the question is: Why is Course object null in Post Endpoint ?

This has nothing to do with EF. It means the JSON payload can't be deserialized as a Course object. You'd have the same problem with a Web API controller or minimal API endpoint and probably even with JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Course>. You didn't post the JSON body so it's impossible to guess what's wrong. Adding "Course":{} guarantees the deserialization will fail and probably result in an invalid body.

That's why I was mentioning it was working for the Put and not the Post with the same payload.
When I'm passing an id as a string in the Guid form in the payload, it's working. But why ? I'm in an entity creation so the Guid should not exist in the front end.
Am I correct ?

Without the JSON and only the relevant code we can't guess. There are a lot of duplicate questions already though. This is 100% an ASP.NET Core model binding issue. Perhaps model binding doesn't like ICollection<Class>. You never see that in DTOs and in EF you only see it when people want to implement lazy loading. Or perhaps the missing Class type has read only properties or constructor parameters that don't allow its construction. Course doesn't contain any ClassCourse properties

Can you deserialize that JSON with JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Course>(string) in the first place? If not, neither can ASP.NET Core. How are you calling the API? If you call if from a browser check the actual request in the Network tab of the Developer Tools

Post the JSON content

Ok I understood, when I post without the Id it deserializes well, when I put an empty string as Id it doesn't recognize it as a Guid at deserialization, that's why it was passing with the put (Id as a Guid) and not with the post (Id as empty string).

An empty string isn't a valid Guid. Either make the field nullable or assign Guid.Empty to it, which is all zeroes

Thanks for your patience as well as your comments which did drive me into the understanding.
